# Spring boot rest tomcat deployment error

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, deployment, spring-boot

I have created a rest api using Spring rest and Spring boot. When I am trying to deploy it on tomcat on linux server, I get following error:

```
rror during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class       at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
```

I am following exact Spring boot instruction for tomcat. My question is that I am not using anything related to Jersey for my application (apis) then why it is looking for Jersey related code, and how I can fix it.

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Contoller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/cmscontent")
public class BatchController {
```

Comment: can you share your pom.xml, it might contain the issue

Comment: What's the complete stacktrace of the `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: @Raja, I am using Gradle and here are dependencies.compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4")
    compile("net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.0") {
        exclude(group: "org.slf4j")
    }
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support") {
        exclude(module: 'quartz')
    }
Since, I am not using Jersey not sure, why it is complaining for jersey

Comment: @Andy, System does not allow me to send...Let me see if I can upload something on googleDocs.

Comment: @Andy I have uploaded it to googledocs. can you please share your email and I can sent it.

Comment: Somewhere public would be better. Why not create a Gist on GitHub?

Comment: All my necessary files there on this. Application.java, gradle.build and errror.....https://github.com/raigeek/SpringBoot

Answer (score 0):

If you add `spring-boot-starter-web` into your POM file as dependency,
it will include embedded web container (Tomcat by default) automatically.
Therefore, just execute JAR directly without deploying it to any web container.